# Changed my blog's URL: what next?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, url, search-engine-indexing

I started working on a blog from last month. My blogs URL was quite big (for ex. `http://my-old-long-url-blog.blogspot.com`). I used it because I thought having 2-3 keywords in my URL will help me (I am not really sure that it really helps?).

My blog was getting 22-25 visitors everyday. I changed it's URL 4 days ago & added new URL. `http://autohippo.blogspot.com`. In blogger, there is a provision to edit & take any URL, anytime we want.

***Now:***

1. My old URL posts are still indexed (they appear in Google for particular keywords).
2. My new URL posts are indexed but not ranked (i.e. when I search`site:http://autohippo.blogspot.com` they appear but i haven't received single visit from Google yet.
3. I added this URL to my webmasters & even submitted sitemap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well since it's an entirely different sub-domain you would need to create 301 redirects from your old website to the new site, however i'm not sure how to go about doing that on Blogspot. Creating and submitting a new sitemap is the right way to start. But to automatically redirect visitors from the old site to the new site isn't easy on blogspot.

This is how to setup a meta redirect

http://www.spiceupyourblog.com/2011/01/automatic-redirect-blogger-blogs-url.html

The problem is that search engines probably wont pass on any credit like they would a 301 redirect.

Here is a discussion about 301 redirects in Blogspot and some possibilities

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/blogger/thread?tid=6d25a21c8e1e9025&hl=en

Comment: we can't do 301 on blogger. usually how much time does it take for any new site to get ranked??

Comment: There's no way to say how long before you are indexed, and cached. Update your content as often as you can, continue to submit your new site maps, and get some relevant back links

Comment: Okay, tahnks . i wil follow what you & john have menationed .

Answer (score 2):

It will take some time for your old posts to drop out of Google. Partially because it takes a while for Google to drop pages that no longer exist (they give them a chance to return) and partially because your old site was probably not crawled frequently and it will take some time for Google to realize they do no exist anymore. But they will disappear from Google's search results eventually.

By changing your URLs you are essentially starting over. You cannot expect your new pages to rank as well as the old pages because they have lost all of the links your old pages accumulated over time. In other words you shot yourself in the foot by changing your URLs. If you want them to rank as well as they did before then you will need to use the information contained in the link provided by Anagio and do 301 redirects from your old URLs to your new URLs. 301 redirects tell Google that your pages have moved and where to find them. That includes associating any links they have acquired with the new URLs. Without the SEO value those links have to offer you're back at square one.

Comment: actually john, i did not have any backlinks as i had started the blog in last month.& i thought it is best time to change the url else if start getting decent traffic it will difficult for me change the url...

Answer (score 0):

No there is little or no benefit of having keyword in domain after the EMD algo update.
EMD is exact match domain update which says the having keyword in domain will not be benificial unless it has quality backlinks. Here are the details of that update

http://searchengineland.com/google-emd-update-research-and-thoughts-137340
http://www.webpronews.com/google-emd-update-what-is-its-real-impact-2012-10
http://searchengineland.com/google-emd-update-research-and-thoughts-137340

Comment: In order to help more precisely the question asker, could you explain why please?

Comment: Please provide references as well.